# Python Regex, how to substitute multiple occurrences with a single pattern?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to make a fuzzy autocomplete suggestion box that highlights searched characters with HTML tags <b></b>

For example, if the user types 'ldi' and one of the suggestions is "Leonardo DiCaprio" then the desired outcome is "**L**eonar**d**o D**i**Caprio". The first occurrence of each character is highlighted in order of appearance.

What I'm doing right now is:

```py
def prototype_finding_chars_in_string():
    test_string_list = ["Leonardo DiCaprio", "Brad Pitt","Claire Danes","Tobey Maguire"]
    comp_string = "ldi" #chars to highlight
    regex = ".*?" + ".*?".join([f"({x})" for x in comp_string]) + ".*?" #results in .*?(l).*?(d).*?(i).*
    regex_compiled = re.compile(regex, re.IGNORECASE)
    for x in test_string_list:
        re_search_result = re.search(regex_compiled, x) # correctly filters the test list to include only entries that features the search chars in order
        if re_search_result:
            print(f"char combination {comp_string} are in {x} result group: {re_search_result.groups()}")
```

results in

```
char combination ldi are in Leonardo DiCaprio result group: ('L', 'D', 'i')
```

Now I want to replace each occurrence in the result groups with `<b>[whatever in the result]</b>` and I'm not sure how to do it.

What I'm currently doing is looping over the result and using the built-in `str.replace` method to replace the occurrences:

```py
def replace_with_bold(result_groups, original_string):
    output_string: str = original_string
    for result in result_groups:
        output_string = output_string.replace(result,f"<b>{result}</b>",1)
    
    return output_string
```

This results in:

```
Highlighted string: <b>L</b>eonar<b>d</b>o D<b>i</b>Caprio
```

But I think looping like this over the results when I already have the match groups is wasteful. Furthermore, it's not even correct because it checked the string from the beginning each loop. So for the input 'ooo' this is the result:

```
char combination ooo are in Leonardo DiCaprio result group: ('o', 'o', 'o')
Highlighted string: Le<b><b><b>o</b></b></b>nardo DiCaprio
```

When it should be `Le<b>o</b>nard<b>o</b> DiCapri<b>o</b>`

Is there a way to simplify this? Maybe regex here is overkill?

Comment: Change your pattern from `.*?(l).*?(d).*?(i).*` to `(l)(.*?)(d)(.*?)(i)` and build your replacement using capture groups content. (note that only odd captures need to be enclosed between b tags)

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this? Do you mean something like `f"<b>{group_1}</b>{group_2}<b>{group_2}</b>{group_3}"`? This sounds like a great idea. But wouldn't omit the first `.*?` yield results that only start with 'l'?

Comment: Omitting the first `.*?` should no be a problem, `re.sub` and `re.search` aren't anchored to the start of the string like `re.match`.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte But what happens to the text before the first match? If I understand you correctly, you're saying I should just composition the results groups one after another. But the text before the first match isn't in the results. Or am I missing something?

Comment: The idea is to build the replacement string (or formatted string as you like) dynamically according to the number of groups.

Comment: *"But what happens to the text before the first match?"*: nothing since it isn't matched.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I will defiantly try it out and report back.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I hit another snag when trying to implement this. When I iterate over the matched groups, I have no idea which one I would surround in HTML tags and which ones I need to leave as is. And if I used name groups, then each group needs a unique name, no?

Comment: Don't use named groups. The groups you have to surround have always a odd number (1,3,5,7...)

Comment: But this isn't always the case. If the characters to match are 'leo' and the term is "Leonardo DiCaprio" then the groups that need matching are sequential one after the other (1,2,3)

Comment: No, it isn't because `(.*?)`s are empty that they don't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way using re.split:

```
test_string_list = ["Leonardo DiCaprio", "Brad Pitt", "Claire Danes", "Tobey Maguire"]

def filter_and_highlight(strings, letters):
    
    pat = re.compile( '(' + (')(.*?)('.join(letters)) + ')', re.I)
    
    results = []
    
    for s in strings:
        parts = pat.split(s, 1)
        
        if len(parts) == 1: continue
        
        res = ''
        for i, p in enumerate(parts):
            if i & 1:
                p = '<b>' + p + '</b>'
                
            res += p
            
        results.append(res)
        
    return results

filter_and_highlight(test_string_list, 'lir')
```

A particularity of `re.split` is that captures are included by default as parts in the result. Also, even if the first capture matches at the start of the string, an empty part is returned before it, that means that searched letters are always at odd indexes in the list of substrings.

Comment: Thank you for your help! It indeed does work.  Can you explain the `i & 1`? Does it evaluate to True because the binary representation of all odd numbers ends with `1`?

Comment: @Curtwagner1984: indeed diabolo, it's the bitwise operator AND.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```py
for result in result_groups:
    output_string = re.sub(fr'(.*?(?!<b>))({result})((?!</b>).*)',
         r'\1<b>\2</b>\3',
         output_string,
         flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

on each iteration first occurrence of result (`?` makes `.*` lazy this together does the magic of first occurrence) will be replaced by `<b>result</b>` if it is not enclosed by tag before (`(?!<b>)` and `(?!</b>)` does that part) and `\1 \2 \3` are first, second and third group additionally we will use `IGNORECASE` flag to make it case insensitive.